# Stuck on welcome screen & language selection

Tags: settings, custom-roms

I installed custom ROM before this I ported it. The rom is **[amzen 5 kitkat](http://serbadroid.blogspot.com/2014/11/rom-amzen-5-kitkat-for-mt6572.html)**  but I have problem with welcome screen. I can't choose language I can switch between languages. Is it possible to modify to not show welcome screen and instead of it show home screen and in settings you can choose language?

Comment: There's a build.prop line that disables setup wizard, and alternatively you could just remove the APK of setup wizard altogether (albeit with some consequences). Just giving you some ideas to go with, since it's still a ROM development question and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Own answer

Auto rotate helps.

More concretely the landscape orientation because you see in the bottom half of button without text (i.e no 'go next' or something else) and can go next so I clicked but I don't know why UI is so big. I suppose the author built UI big. That's why you can not see button next in portrait orientation